# Create a column in a Sharepoint Content Type using Graph API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

Based on the documentation found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/contenttype-post-columns?view=graph-rest-1.0

In order to add a column definition to a content type, the call is pretty simple.

POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/contentTypes/{contentType-id}/columns](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite-id%7D/contentTypes/%7BcontentType-id%7D/columns)
Content-Type: application/json

```
{
    "sourceColumn@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/root/columns/99ddcf45-e2f7-4f17-82b0-6fba34445103"
}
```

I can also use the following URL POST /sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/contentTypes/{contentType-id}/columns

Now I implemented a basic Http Client that can call Sharepoint easily.
Here is my implementation:

```
public ColumnDefinition addContentTypeColumn(
        GraphServiceClient<Request> requestGraphServiceClient,
        String siteId,
        String listId,
        String contentTypeId,
        ColumnDefinition columnDefinition) {

    return requestGraphServiceClient
            .sites(siteId)
            .lists(listId)
            .contentTypes(contentTypeId)
            .columns()
            .buildRequest()
            .post(columnDefinition);
}
```

the url is correct but i have an exception thrown by Sharepoint:

```
mai 23, 2023 4:17:10 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 408Graph service exception
mai 23, 2023 4:17:10 PM com.microsoft.graph.logger.DefaultLogger logError
SEVERE: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.http.GraphServiceException: Error code: invalidRequest
Error message: sourceColumn not present.
```